# R shiny - User editable text input from UI

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Below logic gives Dropdown's from UI and working well.

dynamic textInput with R shiny ( USer can enter any text )
Need Help: Now I want user input STRING on "col_a4" to match user input string rather then drop down on"col_a4".

Used shiny dashboard and DT library in my work. Is there any way i can include search option in UI to search in the -col_a4

```
     ###### UI.R 
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Demo"),selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",choices = c("Book1", "Book2", "Book3")),           
      column(width=2,uiOutput("col_a1")),
      column(width=2,uiOutput("col_a2")),
      column(width=2,uiOutput("col_a3")),
      column(width=2,uiOutput("col_a4")),
      div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 8px;",HTML("<br>")),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Click Me"),
      uiOutput("dt")
    ))
###### server.R 
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server = shinyServer(function(input,output){

    global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset,
             "Book1" = Book1,
             "Book2" = Book2,
             "Book3" = Book3)
    })

    output$Dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
      data=datasetInput()
    })

    output$col_a1 = renderUI({
      selectInput("col_a1", "Select col_a1:", datasetInput()$col_a1,selectize = TRUE,multiple = T)
    })

    output$col_a2 = renderUI({
      selectInput("col_a2", "Select col_a2:", datasetInput()$col_a2,selectize = TRUE,multiple = T)
    })

    output$col_a3 = renderUI({
      selectInput("col_a3", "Select col_a3:", datasetInput()$col_a3,selectize = TRUE,multiple = T)
    })

    output$col_a4 = renderUI({
      selectInput("col_a4", "Select col_a4:", datasetInput()$col_a4,selectize = TRUE,multiple = T)
    })

    output$Counter = renderText(
      {
        output$Clicked = renderText(0)
        isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
        filter = datasetInput()$col_a1%in%input$col_a1 &
          datasetInput()$col_a2%in%input$col_a2 &
          datasetInput()$col_a3%in%input$col_a3 &
          datasetInput()$col_a4%in%input$col_a4 
        DataFilter1 = paste("Total Number of Records",nrow(subset(datasetInput(),
                                                                  filter)))
      }
    )


    observeEvent(input$Click,{
      output$Clicked = renderText(1)
      isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
      output$Table = DT::renderDataTable(
        {
          input$Click
          filter = datasetInput()$col_a1%in%input$col_a1 &
            datasetInput()$col_a2%in%input$col_a2 &
            datasetInput()$col_a3%in%input$col_a3 &
            datasetInput()$col_a4%in%input$col_a4
          DataFilter = subset(datasetInput(),filter)
        })

      output$Datasetaa1 <- renderDataTable({
        data=Table()
      })

      output$mytable11 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(Datasetaa1[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
      })


    output$dt <- renderUI({if(global$refresh == FALSE) return()
                          dataTableOutput('mytable11')})


    })

    myout = reactive({
      filter = datasetInput()$col_a1%in%input$col_a1 &
        datasetInput()$col_a2%in%input$col_a2 &
        datasetInput()$col_a3%in%input$col_a3 &
        datasetInput()$col_a4%in%input$col_a4
      DataFilter = subset(datasetInput(),filter)
    })



    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename=function() {
        paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(myout(),file)
      },
      contentType = "text/plain"
    )
})
```